# Greatest Common Divisor (GCD)

Tags: python, list, for-loop, set, greatest-common-divisor

```
def get_divs(z):
      return [i for i in range(1, z) if z % i == 0]

def gcd(x, y):
      x_div=get_divs(x)
      y_div=get_divs(y)
      cd=set(x_div).intersection(y_div)
      gcd=cd[-1]
      print("The GCD of",x,"and",y,"is",gcd)
      return 1
```

I'm trying to get this program to compute the Greatest Common Divisor (GCD) of two user-entered, positive integers(x, and y). The set function doesn't return a list that can be indexed. Any suggestions as to how I can find the GCD?

Comment: You could try converting the set to a list using `list(cd)`.  Alternatively, if you want the largest element of `cd`, use `max(cd)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what the algo should look like.

```
findGCD(int firstNum, int secondNum){
int smaller; int bigger;int remainder;
if(firstNum < secondNum) {
    smaller = firstNum;
    bigger = secondNum;
}  
else {
    smaller =  secondNum;
    bigger = firstNum;
}

while(true) {
    remainder = bigger % smaller;
    if(remainder == 0) {
         break;
    }
    else {
         bigger = smaller;
         smaller = remainder;
    }
}
return smaller;
}
```